# Which image/picture/photo related tags need to be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have several related tags that have significant overlap:

- <s>[image](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image) × 78</s> -- merged into "images"
- [images](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images) × 175
- [photo](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo) × 10
- [pictures](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pictures) × 6

Comment: I retagged questions under [tag:pictures] to [tag:photo], since there were a small number of them

Answer (score 1):

The questions tagged with `photo` are specific to *photos*. The questions tagged with `pictures` also seem specific to photos.

Questions tagged with `image` and `images` reference both the singular and plural use of "images".

Therefore, `pictures` should be merged into `photos`, and `image` should be merged into `images`.

Comment: The "image" to "images" one is pretty straightforward, so I went ahead with it.  I'll wait a little while for additional feedback before proceeding with the others.

Comment: Sounds good. They can click on the [photos](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo) tag to see what I meant.

Comment: Not sure pictures should be merged with photos, they are two different things. A picture can be a drawing, painting, digital art, etc, but they are not photographs. It's more logical that images and pictures are the same.

Answer (score 0):

All these tags mean the same thing and should be merged into [images](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images) which is the most popular.